# How can I live like a normal teenager with my super strict parents?

Tags: teen, parents, communication, independence

I am 16 and a junior in high school. I have an older sister who is 22 and live with both of my parents.

My parents are super strict compared to my friends' parents. They are very religious, which I am not, so they don't let me do many things. 
I am not allowed to go out with friends all the time. I sure do go out with them at times, but it usually takes me a good amount of time to convince them into letting me go. All my friends are very free and they go out whenever they want with whoever they want.

I am not allowed to date at all, they are very strict about boys and think that "girls and guys can't be just friends". It's irritating because I have a lot of close guy friends and I can't hang out with them. They only let me go to malls (only 2 of them which are like 5 minutes away from home) but meeting up at the mall with my friends every single time is really boring. 
I tried to kill myself 3 years ago and after begging for years they finally let me see a therapist. They don't know much about mental issues and they always say stuff like "What problems could you possibly have to see a therapist?".

I used to have a boyfriend back then but when they found out my mom kept telling me to break up with him and now they are telling me they would ground me if I ever date someone.

I used to attend a school like Catholic schools but for my religion. (I am Muslim but as I said, I don't care about religion unlike my parents.) They didn't want me to go to a normal school at first because they thought I would rebel against them.

Since they are very religious and my mom wears a headscarf, I am not allowed to wear anything above the knee or to expose my shoulders in any way. I am also not allowed to wear anything like crop tops. I am a person who likes their independence a lot and I feel like I am trapped in my own home.

I wrote them a letter of 3 pages about this issue since I am better at writing down than talking. They said that "they didn't agree with me and I had every kind of freedom a 16 year old girl could have". 
My sister is in his last year in college and she is still not allowed to leave home. I am going to start college in 2 years and I am not allowed to leave home either. They keep telling us that we can leave home after we get married. I don't understand how they expect me to get married when I'm not allowed to date at all.

They pick me up and drop me off everywhere and don't let me do anything by myself outside the house. I wish they let me take care of myself more so that I could gain some experience about life in general.

I don't want to waste my teenage years like this. Please don't say "that I have to live with it" or "it's a phase and I'll grow out of it". These are sentences that praise problematic parents and I don't agree with them.

Also, I love my parents a lot so I don't want to rebel against them and make them sad. They care for us a lot and want the best for us but all my mental issues are caused because of them and I wish they understood this. 
Please give me some advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I as a teenager do about my insanely strict parents?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/33077/what-can-i-as-a-teenager-do-about-my-insanely-strict-parents)

Comment: @Anne: I agree that the question seems very similar at face value, but from the details of this question, I don't see much reason to think that the answers offered up in that question will work as well for this poster.

Comment: How  do your parents feel about you getting a job, or volunteering somewhere you like, or playing a sport/doing a hobby in the afternoons outside of your house? What you need is an excuse to get out your house that your parents can't argue with.

Comment: Hi dia, I'm sorry to hear about your situation. It sounds like you do have parents who limit your freedom far beyond what's usual and called-for. But since you have a therapist to talk with, wouldn't it be better to raise these issues with him/her? This person is much closer to you, knows you much better and also knows your situation much better. Usually the more you know about a problem, the better the chance to find a solution. The solution might even involve outside help, but your therapist in a much better position to advise you on this.

Comment: @Stacey: my parents are okay with me having hobbies, i used to take art classes last year but quit because of my anxiety and other mental issues. other than that they won't let me get a job and it is pretty hard to find a decent job here in turkey at the age of 16. i will try to see if i can volunteer somewhere! thank you!

Comment: @Pascal: i talk to my therapist about this all the time, but since i started seeing her lately, we couldn't come up with a solution yet. she sees my parents once in a while so maybe she can help me with this whole thing. thank you!

Comment: "I love my parents a lot so I don't want to rebel against them and make them sad." I'm afraid this sentiment muddles the question. What do you want to know? How to disagree without hurting someone's feelings? Or something else? Please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: @anon: They are very sensitive, as well as I am, and they are especially very protective of me after my suicide attempt. I know they are trying to protect me, but they're limiting my life at this point. I need to have at least some experience in life before I become an adult. Also, they never wanted me to go to a normal school, so I'm scared they'd transfer me to a religious school again, take my phone and forbid me from leaving the house except for school days.

Comment: @dia does your school offer internship experiences? If so, would you be allowed to do this? Also, have you thought about leading a prayer/faith group for other young people? I’m not sure if this would be allowed at your school, but maybe at a park near home? Who’s going to know how much time you all actually praying, if you know what I mean. Finally, if you can’t go anywhere alone, is there anyone your parents trust and who is sympathetic to your situation that you could enlist to chaperone? Another (less strict) parent? A teacher?

Comment: @Jax: Sadly, no, my school doesn't offer any internship experiences. I'll be going to college in 2 years so I want to go abroad to study then. They didn't let my sister go abroad and now she blames them for the things she missed out on, so they are willing to send me abroad, but for a year at max. They say they won't let me go to college in another city though. Also no, I don't know my friends parents' nor do they. They only let me leave the house with my sister if I want to go somewhere far, but my sister is no different from them most of the time so it doesn't really change anything for me.

Comment: Off topic, but it just occurred to me that Turkish high schools (or yours, anyway) seem to offer excellent English lessons.

Comment: @Pascal: Thank you for your sweet compliment :) I've been into learning English ever since I was around 9, so I especially studied very hard to learn it in the best way I can, and maybe I got lucky because all of my teachers were amazing!

Answer (score 9):

This is a difficult situation you're in. At 16 it is reasonable to be allowed a certain degree of independence, and sometimes it can be very difficult for parents to give you that independence.

**1) Compromise**

The best place to start is to look for an area of compromise. You need to get out the house, so if you can think of a hobby or volunteer opportunity that allows you to get away from your home some afternoons a week. This will allow you to get some space and time away from your parents. Something that you enjoy and fits within their rules. (Perhaps even they may find that driving you back and forth is such a pain that they may let you go on your own!)

**2) Work with your parents' religion**

Even if you're not as religious as they are, respecting their beliefs as much as you can will earn their trust. Volunteering is a good option because it's highly regarded in Islam. Hang out with Muslim friends if you can. These are things your parents can't argue with. If there are religious things you can tolerate doing, it's worth it to earn their trust, and then they'll be more likely to give you freedoms in return. There will be plenty of opportunities to discuss religion when you're older, but right now you need to work with what you have.

**3) Talk to a trusted adult**

Talk to a trusted adult. Perhaps you have a counsellor at school, or a teacher you trust, or your therapist. Perhaps they can give you advice that's more specific to your situation than we can. You aren't alone, even though it can feel like that sometimes, and to have someone on your side can really help make a day to day plan.

**4) This is going to end eventually**

In a couple of years time you're going to be an adult, and your parents are going to have a lot less power over you. You will have the option to choose to leave and function independently of them. It's your choice to decide what the relationship looks like then, depending on what level you're comfortable with. But before then try not to do/say anything that you'll regret later on.

**5) Parents are complicated**

Parents can be very afraid. I know - I'm one too. I don't know the motivations behind your parents actions but they are probably not trying to be difficult on purpose, they're just afraid of letting you go.

Comment: So you're a worried parent too, I get that. Bet you've never told your kids they "can leave home after they get married" and then said they can't date, though? I think we may be in over our heads here in a real way, and I think your 4) and 5) are great general advice, but I just don't see that we have reason to assume it'll apply in this case.

Comment: @DavidHedlund It's very difficult to know the full story from one post, and two conservative answers are here already, so I decided to go the practical direction. I suspect also we have inherent biases against Islam that will cause certain knee-jerk reactions. Since dating in Islam is pretty much always with marriage in mind, perhaps her parents intended that she can't date *now* at 16. Not that I'm excusing them, but I wouldn't attribute to malice something that can be easily explained otherwise. I grew up in an extremely religious family and am very familiar with this conservative worldview.

Comment: Wish comments got more attention, because this states well what we should all remember in answering people from different cultures.

Comment: @Stacey I am inclined to say it's a bias against Islam to not think them able to be held to the same standard as us for basic human rights. Islam is a *vast* community. It has tons and tons of reasonable practitioners. So when we see something that doesn't look right, we shouldn't excuse them on the basis of culture. This isn't two cultures colliding, this family is going through an inter-cultural conflict. There are warning signs in this post that lead me to think that you may well be giving false reassurance here, and I think that's the less cautious approach.

Comment: @DavidHedlund - Again, I think you are out of line here. The world is not made up of cultures only like your own. To accuse us of being unable to think as 'clearly' as you do is inappropriate. Please stop imposing your standards on everyone.

Comment: item 5 is important here. Having dated the son of and lived in the home of his VERY religious (Roman Catholic) parents I have witnessed first hand the fear these people felt. One the one hand, they feared losing their son by alienating themselves from him by being too strict. On the other, they feared losing him to sin if they allowed him to do what he wanted, even within reason. It was painful for them to let him date me (a non-RC “sinner”). They took me into their home when I got kicked out of mine, bc they were good people. Truly good. I only really appreciated what they did...

Comment: ...for me after I became a parent to a teenager myself. The battle they waged between their beliefs and their desire to be good, effective parents couldn’t have been easy. My ex fought his parents tooth and nail, and violently disagreed with them, their beliefs, their rules...his sister was much wiser. She *understood* them, *respected* their faith, made sure they knew she did, and she was *given* much more freedom as a result. For the OP, really understanding her parents’ fears (5) and beliefs (2) and empathizing with them may in fact help OP get *some* much-deserved freedom.

Comment: @Jax you've hit upon the thing I really struggled to convey in this answer. With understanding and a wise action she can help significantly in this transition, however I had a hard time finding the nuance to convey that without coming across as condescending ("Put yourself in your parents shoes... ") and that level of insight into the situation really can't be taught, some *adults* still don't have it. I had to settle on giving a practical example (2) instead.

Comment: @anon: I really don't see how you read that into my comment. To me it seems like the opposite of what I'm saying. But I think I've made my case as clearly as I can, so I won't persevere.

Comment: @DavidHedlund: I get what you're saying about not letting culture be an excuse for harmful practices, but I think the threshold is too high in this case. If Dia lived anywhere in the EU, chances are contacting social services wouldn't do much good because they are notoriously understaffed and dealing with *really bad cases of abuse*, so they triage their cases. Dia would most likely be filed under "possibly problematic, but no immediate intervention necessary". I think what Stacey is trying to do is suggest things for Dia to do that can actually work, even if they're not ideal solutions.

Comment: @Pascal: that's a different argument altogether. We could discuss what would work, but that's miles apart from anon's apparent suggestion that intervening at all is problematic. It seems they miss that op is also from Muslim culture, and whoever we side with, it'll be within the confines of the inter-cultural variation. But I'm repeating myself. Happy to elaborate in chat but won't push that line any further here.

Comment: @DavidHedlund - I never stated tat intervening at all is problematic. I upvoted two answers here supportive of the OP. It's your comments that I find intolerant.

Answer (score 6):

*I offer up this answer with some reluctance, because having read Stacey's answer, I think hers goes in the same direction, but is much better. But since I wrote it, I guess I can as well share it.*

> Please don't say "that I have to live with it"

I'm sorry, but I think you will have to. Your options are severely limited.

Once you reach the age of majority, you can do whatever you want, provided that you have a way to support yourself. But until then, there really aren't very many things you can do. It sounds like your parents want you to live with them until you marry, and then you'll live with your husband, so in their world view independence is not something they want for you. You don't have to share this view, and once you're 18, you can break with your family and go live the life you want, but I think it's highly unlikely that you'll convince your parents that you need more freedom at 16.

You *could* try to *force* your parents to give you more freedom. One way to do this would be to find a social services representative (or a teacher) and tell him/her that your development is endangered at home. Teachers have a duty to report when they suspect or are told that children are endangered, and this might lead to a (cursory) investigation. But this investigation would most likely conclude that since you don't get beaten black and blue, have enough clothes to wear, get sent to school regularly and get to eat regular meals, you are therefore not in any kind of danger and that your parents control over you doesn't need to be limited.

Another way might be to petition a court for emancipation (which is possible in turkey at your age and would make you a legal adult before age 18, but chances that you can actually pull this off are very, very slim), and you might not want to, because then you'd be on your own (without all the good things your parents do for you).

While your parents are very strict, I don't think they're actually doing anything that would be considered harmful by the Turkish legal system. So again, your options are severely limited.

I think your best bet is to carve out as much freedom as you can, and to prepare yourself for the moment when you *can* decide for yourself. You'll have to decide what you value most (right now, you seem to be confused about that - you want more freedom, you think you have "problematic parents", but you also say you don't want to rebel or make them sad): Is it your independence, your ties to your family, a good education? Because I think you might not be able to get everything, so it's good to know what's really important to you.

You can try to argue with your parents. Find out what they have planned for you. Find out why it is important to them. Then start looking for loopholes and logical inconsistencies you can exploit. Your college education, for example: What will it be for? Do your parents expect you to find work between the time you finish your college education and the time you marry? Do they expect you to work once you're married? If not, why have a college education at all? If they expect you to work, why not start early so you can get some practice, which will help you find a job later on? If you can start earning some money, even if you turn it over to your parents for now, a job, even if it's just serving coffee in a coffee house or stacking food in a store, might come in handy when you turn 18 and have to decide how to proceed. Also, it takes you out of your home and puts you in contact with other people, which might also come in handy later on.

Another example, again starting from the college education: If they want you to have a college education, they must also want you to think for yourself. Once you marry, are you supposed to just do what your husband tells you (in which case, again, why have a college education?), or do they see marriage as a partnership of two equals? If so, shouldn't they help prepare you for how decisions are reached, and how compromises work? Compromises are reached by both sides arguing and then finding common ground - something you can start practicing now, with them.

You might not win many of these arguments - but maybe you'll win some.

Also, I hesitate to write this, but parents don't need to know everything that goes on in the life of a 16-year-old, if you get my drift.

Comment: Don't know why you removed this perfectly good answer...

Comment: @anongoodnurse: I thought Stacy's answer, which beat mine by a few minutes, was clearer, more concise and offered more practical advice than mine, but I'll go with your judgement and offer it up anyway.

Comment: @Pascal I think your answer is very good on its own. Sometimes things need to be said multiple ways, and the "looking for loopholes" paragraph is also what I was going for but couldn't figure out how to put it in a general way like you did.

Comment: I agree with @Stacey; sometimes it helps not only to have things said differently, but it also reinforces a viewpoint. I upvoted both answers.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it asks the important question “what do you value most” and because it talks about getting a job as a potential solution. If possible, a job where you can earn tips would be ideal so that some of the money can be squirreled away for the glorious day when emancipation finally happens. The harsh reality is that it’s VERY difficult to just set out on your own at age 18 years, 0 days, even with preparation and support. Homelessness is a real risk.

Comment: @Jax a job is what I thought of too, but she mentioned in a comment that it would be very difficult for her to get one. That's why I started with something like volunteering instead because charity is highly regarded in Islam ( and it may open her parents up to her getting a job later)

Comment: I absolutely LOVE this answer for 2 reasons : 1- Asking yourself what you value most and 2- asking your parents for their reasonings. Many times, people have a need to just flow with some pre-defined steps of life without giving it much thought, or connecting the steps to each other. Asking questions makes them stop and give it a thought. Even if they really think "You must do what your husband tells you to, but you still need a college education just because" they may hesitate to say it out loud with a straight face. That might force them to reconsider their norms.

Answer (score 6):

My parents were fairly strict, although not quite as strict as you've described. I wasn't allowed to date at all until I was 16, and then only group dates. I had a strict curfew, and they always had to know who I was with, where I was going, and when I would be back. If any of those plans changed, I had to call first. I was expected to reserve Sundays all day, and Monday and Wednesday evenings for religious activities.

My siblings constantly complained that they never got to do anything, while it seemed to them that I had an unfair amount of independence. What did I do differently from them? I worked within the rules instead of complaining about the rules and sulking at home.

I found that keeping my parents apprised of the "big three questions," as I called them, was a small price to pay. In fact, as an adult, I do this with my wife out of common courtesy. Group dates were certainly better than no dates, and also took a lot of the pressure off. Getting home before curfew was a lot better than not going out at all.

I would suggest exploring the freedom you have within the rules. It's probably more than you think. Try planning specific activities with defined start and end times instead of "hanging out." Ask your parents if your friends can hang out at your house, which they might be comfortable enough with to ease their restrictions on boys. Think of other activities your parents would be more comfortable with that would still be fun for you. Making friends with some Muslim youths might ease some of your parents' concerns, and you might find you have a common struggle. Introduce your parents to your friends, boy and girl. It's a lot easier for them to distrust someone they don't know. Let your parents see you are cultivating a wide variety of friendships, and not getting too serious too soon. Go out of your way to help your parents not worry, and they will eventually stop worrying (at least on the outside).

Working within the rules and not acting like you're trying to hide something or get away with something builds up trust. That trust leads to easing of restrictions. The few times I missed curfew I did not get in trouble, because my previous behavior had shown my parents I did my best and would have called as soon as I was able.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to write this! Well, I always tell my parents where I am going, with who and when I'll be back home. As I said, since they drop me off and pick me up from everywhere, we usually discuss the time before and during the outing. My friends know most of my friends, have their AND their parents' numbers saved in their contacts, and all of my friends are Muslim. The no boys rule is not something I think I can break since bringing boy friends home was never an option to my sister nor me.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I want to validate your feelings regarding this. From your description, it seems your parents are doing you a big disservice. If they came here for advice, I would tell them that as well. But they're not the ones reaching out, you are. So at the end of the day, it's you who are going to have to face your parents with this. And from your description, it doesn't seem like they place much value in your view. So that's a tough situation to find yourself in, and not one that we can remedy remotely.

When it comes to a child's right to be heard, I usually fall back to article 12 in UN's convetions of the rights of the child:

> States Parties shall assure to the child who is capable of forming his or her own views the right to express those views freely in all matters affecting the child, the views of the child being given due weight in accordance with the age and maturity of the child.

You are almost adult, and it seems that your view is given almost zero weight, so that to me is a clear conflict. Now, the convention deals with the responsibilities of states, so it's not really applicable to parents, but I usually hold that if your parenting doesn't live up to basic human rights, as a parent, that's a red flag that you really should take a step back and reflect on that. You could see if that bites on them, but frankly, I'm not hopeful it will. They seem to have a clear idea on what they want from you, given all that you've gone through to no avail so far, it's not obvious that you will be able to sway them.

If I come across as saying that "you'll have to live with it", it's not because I share your parents views, it's because I think this is out of reach for anyone on this forum. I think you should reach out to someone who will be able to get in direct contact with your parents, which we won't, such as some social services in your country.

> They keep telling us that we can leave home after we get married. I don't understand how they expect me to get married when I'm not allowed to date at all.

This is a red flag for me. This goes beyond just parents being protective. I get that what they're saying doesn't appear to compute to you, but this does work if you'll marry a husband of their choosing. If they are serious about that, this tells me that you will not have your independence once you turn adult. They will yield control over you, but not to you, to your husband. The fact that you do not want to rebel against your parents speaks to your credit, but from this it seems that if you want autonomy, you will have to wrestle it from your parents hands.

Comment: "This is a red flag for me...there is a sinister logic to it." It is not a sinister logic, it is a cultural issue. -1 Your ill opinion of another culture does not mean your culture is right and theirs is wrong. (FWIW, there's a subculture right here in the US which does not allow dating either. The people are not all insane or abusive. They just believe in something different.)

Comment: @anon: forget me, it seem to be the opinion of OP as well. And I don't see that the number or geographic spread of such occurrences makes a difference.

Comment: If op was happy with it, I'd have no issue at all. But then there'd also be no question here. Your comment can well be extrapolated to the entire question, as everything here may have a cultural explanation, but that seems utterly unhelpful.

Comment: Your answer demonstrates no understanding of cultures different from your own. This is a world-wide site (at least to English speakers) and describing a cultural phenomenon as *sinister* is out of line. She's loved, not getting beaten (you would have some ground to stand on there.)

Comment: @anon: oh is this a wording issue? I don't mind changing that, I'll accept it may come across wrong, I'm not a native speaker. As for the answer in itself, I hold the rights of the child to be pan-cultural, and whenever they are violated, which I believe happens frequently in American culture as well, mind you, judging from what I see here, I don't think it can be tolerated under the guise of cultural sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any chance you could excel at your schoolwork or extracurricular activities? This might lead to an offer to attend a prestigious university that's far from home, perhaps even in another country. If your parents value education highly, they might support you in attending a university away from home. Even if you're not a stellar student now, if you work hard, you could probably be one by the time you apply to colleges.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not a Social Worker or an expert in this field, and the law governing this stuff varies from country to country, so it would be best for you to discuss this with a trusted authority at your school if it's publicly funded/non-Muslim, or with your therapist. This is my advice:

If you are currently seeing a therapist, you may want to tell them about this, as well as about your previous suicide attempt. They are likely a mandatory reporter, so if you tell them about this stuff, you might be able to ask them about what would be required for the Department of Child Services (or your locale's equivalent) to remove you from your home and place you in a foster home, or for you to be given an involuntary stay at a local mental hospital - with a previous suicide attempt on the record, it might be possible that confessing suicidal thoughts may be sufficient to get you confined to a suicide wing. While neither of these are ideal situations, they would remove you from the control of your parents, at least on the short term. You might also want to look up local Women's Shelters, and the rules that apply to them; it's possible that you're old enough that they'd count you as an adult if you run away from home and go to one.

However, the real thing you have to look forward to is very simple: **when you turn 18, in a Western country, that means you're an adult, and they're not (legally) allowed to stop you from leaving if you want to.** You can just pack your stuff, hop on a bus, and just catch a ride to another city if you really want to, and there's nothing they can do to stop you without breaking the law. If this is the route you intend to take, I would suggest looking up Women's Shelters, or build a social network outside the Muslim subculture that you've been living in, to minimize the risk of your parents finding you. I would personally recommend Christian churches, since many churches have strong charitable arms that might be able to assist you (even if you're not a Christian), and they're unlikely to rat you out to Muslim family members who come looking if they know your situation.